# Polynomials that gives us the affine piece of a projective algebraic set

Tags: algebraic-geometry

So it has been shown that projective algebraic sets are locally affine, ie. at every point $x\in X \subset P^n$, there is a open neighborhood (open in $X$) that is isomorphic to a affine algebraic set (closed set in A^n).

[image]

Now for the highlighted part, it turns out we even know the polynomials whose vanishing ideal is in fact that set, but why is it actually enough to just substitute $x_i=1$ ?

Answer (score 1):

I think this should be enough:

Recall that the sets $U_i$ are defined as follows:

$$
U_i= \left\{ P \in \mathbb P^n \vert x_i \neq 0  \right\}
$$

Because $\lambda \cdot P = P$ ($\lambda \neq 0$) for all points $P \in \mathbb P^n$, we get the familiar isomorhphism $U_i \simeq \mathbb A^n$ like this:

$$
P = \left(x_0, \ldots, x_i, \ldots, x_n\right) = (x_0/x_i , \ldots, 1, \ldots, x_n/x_i) \mapsto (x_0/x_i, \ldots, 1, \ldots, x_n/x_i) \mapsto  (x_0/x_i, \ldots, x_n/x_i)
$$
(the last isomorphism is dropping the i'th coordinate). We're essentially saying that $U_i \simeq \mathbb A^{n+1} \cap H$, where $H$ is the hyperplane in $\mathbb A^{n+1}$ defined by $x_i=1$.

Now for your question: an algebraic variety in projective space is defined by a set of homogeneous polynomial equations in $n+1$ variables. But to see how the same equations looks on $U_i$, we can use the isomorphism above to consider the equations in $\mathbb A^n$ instead. But the isomorphism is essentially just seeing the all points in $U_i$ can be written with the i'th coordinate equal to 1, so we can forget it.

Edit: I see now that your question is basically answered by the parenthesis in the screenshot, which is what I tried to explain. Did this help?